# Can I reference to the info of stackoverflow on other stackexchange sites?

Tags: support, profile-page

For example, can i set the info of my profile on metastackoverflow to the content of my info on stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: That is not a reference (as requested in the question title) either, or is it?

Comment: @H.B.: It's not a "reference" in the sense that updates to one will automatically be reflected in the other. But it's still a heck of a lot easier than Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.